# Typescript is compiling import to use require but browser complains

Tags: javascript, typescript, require

I have set:

```
<script src="./Snake.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

on my HTML file.

and I have `Snake.ts` that I am compiling to JS with the following configuration:

```
{target: "es6", module: "commonjs"}
```

but Typescript is converting my import statements to use the require function (which only works with NodeJS) and so the browser complains about

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined.
```

I am not using require anywhere in my code, but Typescript is automatically converting my import statements to use the require function instead of

```
import Game from './Game';
```

I have tried everything, including switching to and, umd, es2020. It was working yesterday.

How do I compile Typescript code to browser JavaScript code and node NodeJS code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your configuration you are setting the module system to `commonJS`, which uses `require` to import the module.

Set the `module` system to `ES2015/ES6` in the typescript configuration.

```
 {target: "ES6", module: "ES2015"}
```

Comment: changing it in the file didnt work but if i changed it using tsc —module es2015 it works! thank you!! why es2015 and not es2019 or es2020?

Comment: You could use the the higher version, the minimum version requirement for `ES6 module` is `ES2015`.